# Namespace error when using HitTest method on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, namespaces, windows-phone, hittest

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8 using Visual Studio Express for WP and I'm coming across a problem in the following line of a simple hit test:

```
        HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MainCanvas, pt);
```

The two errors I am getting are as follows:

1) The type or namespace name 'HitTestResult' could not be found
2) 'System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper' does not contain a definition for 'HitTest'

I have tried adding 'using System.Windows.Media.HitTestResult' or 'using System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper' but both result in the error that the namespace doesn't exist in System.Windows.Media.

Am I missing a required reference, or are the group of methods/way of hit testing I am using not supported by Windows Phone? (if so is there an alternate way of hit testing user tap input on a canvas element)

Thanks in advance

**SOLVED:** Thanks for the suggestion, this is the correct format...

```
 private void MainCanvas_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = e.GetPosition((Canvas)sender);
        var result = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(pt, MainCanvas);

        if (result != null)
        {             
            //Do what you want in here
        }          
    }
```

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838402%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @SLaks Unfortunately this seems to only be supported in Windows Phone OS 7.0 & 7.1, according to that page (I'm looking for Windows Phone 8 support)

Comment: Try in in WP8; it might work.